# What is scope chain in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> when I used below code:

```
function a(){
  var q = 1;
  function b(){
    console.log(q);
  }
 b();
}

var q= 2;
a();
```

> It gives me output as 1.
>   But when I used below code:

```
function b(){
  console.log(q);
}

function a(){
  var q = 1;
 b();
}

q= 2;
a();
```

> output is 2. and also when I used below code:

```
function a(){
  function b(){ 
    console.log(q);
  }
b();
}

var q= 2;
a();
```

> Again I got Output as 2. I know it is something related to scope chain as I searched in google but didn't understood completely.

Comment: please use the code tag while writing the question for the code part,makes easier to read the code.

Comment: You've oversimplified each example because none of them produce any output since `b()` is never called in any of them. Please create a [mcve] that actually reproduces your issue

Comment: sorry I have corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope chain is simply the locations where identifiers are declared that is searched to resolve the value of an identifier.

It's important to distinguish *where* something is declared vs. *when* something is declared. Just because you declare `q` right before a function call that uses `q` doesn't mean that that is the `q` that will get used - there can be multiple `q` variables, each existing it their own scope.

Before we look at your examples, imagine this scenario. You are in a large room, divided up into cubicles big enough for two workers.  You and your co-worker "Joe" share one cubicle (since you are there, that is your local scope and you share it with Joe). If you and Joe were both sitting in your shared cubicle at the same time and you wanted to talk to Joe, you'd just say "Hey Joe" and Joe would immediately respond. But, what if Joe gets up to get some water at the office water cooler? If you then said, "Hey Joe", he wouldn't be found in your small cubicle scope, so you'd have to widen your search to the entire office (a higher scope that contains the scope your cubicle is in). But, by widening your search to the next higher scope (going up the scope chain), you'd eventually find Joe. Now imagine that the water cooler is shared between two offices on the same floor. You wouldn't find Joe in your cubicle, he wouldn't be in your office, so you'd have to once again widen your search to include other scopes visible to you (the office next door).

Still with me? Now, here's a wrinkle... What if there were different "Joe's" in each of those locations and you the Joe you wanted to talk to was in the other office? When you say "Hey Joe!", the closest one would reply, but that may not be the Joe you had in mind. This is what's happening with your `q` variable. You have more than one declared at different scope levels and the one you expect isn't the closest one to the scope you are calling it from.

```js
function a(){
  // q is declared in this scope and this is the next highest scope to where it is 
  // used for the console.log, so 1 is the output
  var q = 1;
  function b(){
    // q isn't declared in this function's scope, so the next higher scope
    // needs to be checked.
    console.log(q);
  }
 b();
}

// Even though this code runs just before the function call,
// this is creating a different "q" variable in the higest scope
// -- the global scope. When the function runs, it won't need
// to search all the way up to this level to find a declaration
// for q, so 2 isn't what is outputted
var q= 2;

// Now, run the function
a();
```

```js
function b(){
  // Here, there is no q in this local scope,
  // so again, the next highest scope is searched.
  // Since this is NOT a nested function, the next highest
  // scope is the global scope and the q in that scope is found
  // producing 2 as output
  console.log(q);
}

function a(){
 // Create a local q variable that only is accessible from here
 var q = 1;
 
 // Invoke the b function
 b();
}

// Global q is being set
q = 2;

// Invoke the a function
a();
```

```js
function a(){
  // There is no q in this scope, so the next highest scope (the global scope)
  // is checked.
  function b(){ 
    // There is no q in this scope, so the scope of a is checked
    console.log(q);
  }
  b();
}

// Not only is this the Global q, but it's the only q declared
var q= 2;
a();
```